# what's the mean of 'create a node' in kubernetes api

Tags: kubernetes

i fount the api in kubernetes doc:

> Write Operations

HTTP Request
POST /api/v1/nodes

Query Parameters
Parameter   Description
pretty  If 'true', then the output is pretty printed.
Body Parameters
Parameter   Description
body 
Node
Response
Code    Description
200 
Node    OK

[the detail of this api is here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#-strong-write-operations-strong--466)

I test this api. send a post requst with this request body:

> ```
> {"kind": "Node",
>  "apiVersion": "v1",
>  "metadata": {
>  "name": "10.110.17.48"
>  }}
> ```

the response is

```
{
"kind": "Node",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
    "name": "10.110.17.48",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes10.110.17.48",
    "uid": "61bfa1e6-af14-11e7-8194-005056b6695e",
    "resourceVersion": "3684908",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-10-12T06:12:53Z"
},
"spec": {
    "externalID": "10.110.17.48"
},
"status": {
    "daemonEndpoints": {
        "kubeletEndpoint": {
            "Port": 0
        }
    },
    "nodeInfo": {
        "machineID": "",
        "systemUUID": "",
        "bootID": "",
        "kernelVersion": "",
        "osImage": "",
        "containerRuntimeVersion": "",
        "kubeletVersion": "",
        "kubeProxyVersion": "",
        "operatingSystem": "",
        "architecture": ""
    }
}
}
```

then i check the kubectl get nodes

```
[root@master3 yum.repos.d]# kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS     AGE       VERSION
10.110.17.48   NotReady   18m       
master1        Ready      20d       v1.6.4+coreos.0
master2        Ready      20d       v1.6.4+coreos.0
master3        Ready      20d       v1.6.4+coreos.0
slave1         Ready      20d       v1.6.4+coreos.0
slave2         Ready      20d       v1.6.4+coreos.0
slave3         Ready      44m       v1.6.4+coreos.0
```

this node is not ready.

this node is only a centos os,not install the kubelet,kube-proxy,clico-node.

if i use this node?should i install kubelet,kube-proxy,clico-node on this node?

and then,what's the meaning of this api? just notifiy api server to store this node info in etcd?

Answer (score 1):

> and then,what's the meaning of this api? just notifiy api server to store this node info in etcd?

Yup, that's it. POST-ing to an API endpoint does not cause kubernetes to attempt to take any actions on your machine -- that is the entire purpose of running `kubelet` on such a machine: granting kubernetes "permission" and the means to enact changes on a Node

A hypothetical use for POST-ing to that API before kubelet starts up may be -- and I stress *may* be -- to declare your intention to start a Node in the very near future, so if (hypothetically) you only ever wanted 10 Nodes in your cluster, then POST-ing to the API allows notifying your colleagues that you are starting the Node, and they don't have to.